# crystal report 10 report header issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I had a couple of reports which were working properly in crystal version report 9. While exporting the data to excel, it was working properly. But after upgrading to version 10, when we try to export to excel with data only option, the report header is not formating properly. The Report header has 3 rows, but wen I export it to excel(data only), it displays all in same line in version 10 and in different lines in version 9.

if I put it in different report header sections, issue is solved but there are many reports which makes it very difficult to make that change at all places. is there any other solution for this.

Can anybody help me with this.
Any help in this regard is welcome.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Every version of Crystal Reports "tricks up" the Excel export settings and the formatting results they produce. Your only hope is to look at all the Excel output settings and find a way to recreate your expected output. There is a chance getting the EXACT output is not possible in the new version.

Note, your topic has nothing to do with Reporting Services and should not be tagged that way.